# Visual Studio 2019 STL include errors

Tags: c++, include, visual-studio-2019

So I'm trying to organize my projects a little better instead of dumping all my code in the same directory as the solution. So I put the visual studio relevant files in the build folder, and created my main.cpp inside the src folder and the project runs fine with #include iostream and other standard includes. However, I want to now add the include directory path to my project, so I go followed some guides and went into project->C/C++->Additional Include Directories and added the path. If I do #include "tesh.h" in main.cpp it can find test.h fine but now there is a compiler error telling me that it cannot find the standard includes like iostream and cmath. One of the many errors I get is

```
>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath(218,23): error C3861: 'rintf': identifier not found
```

I'm wondering if anything has experienced this before, and what I can do to fix this! Here is my project organization for reference

```
Project 
    include
        test.h
    src
        main.cpp
    build
        .sln
        .vcxproj
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could refer to the DOC: [Compiler Error C3861](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3861?view=vs-2019)

First of all, I suggest you should compare use of identifier to the identifier declaration for case and spelling.

And then, Verify that scope resolution operators and namespace using directives are used correctly. If the identifier is declared in a header file, verify that the header is included before the identifier is referenced. If the identifier is meant to be externally visible, make sure that it is declared in any source file that uses it.

Also check that the identifier declaration or definition is not excluded by conditional compilation directives.